# How to run multiple FFMPEG commands as a batch file in Windows 10/11?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-editor, windows

I have the following code which adds a small overlay text over my video:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vf "drawtext=fontfile=path\font.ttf:text='ABC':fontcolor=black:fontsize=45:box=1:boxcolor=white@1:boxborderw=5:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=50:enable='gte(t,5)',drawtext=fontfile=path\font.ttf:text='DEF':fontcolor=black:fontsize=45:box=1:boxcolor=white@1:boxborderw=5:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=100:enable='gte(t,5)'" -codec:a copy output.mp4
```

I have around videos for which I want to do the same command. I have the 100 commands ready through excel formulas.
Now, can someone please help me how I can execute these 100 FFMPEG commands as a batch file on Windows 11?

Answer (score 0):

Open any txt file editor.
Paste each command separated by newline each (press <kbd>Enter</kbd>).
Save as .bat (not .bat.txt, so click 'All files').
Execute it by right click Run or Execute

Consider making the 100 commands in batch and not Excel next time.

Answer (score 0):

You might also like to make a ".bat/.cmd" file that takes the file name as a parameter
Note the  %%1 is the input file and %%2 is the name of the output file
=>addABC.bat

```
 ffmpeg -i %%1 -vf "drawtext=fontfile=path\font.ttf:text='ABC':fontcolor=black:fontsize=45:box=1:boxcolor=white@1:boxborderw=5:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=50:enable='gte(t,5)',drawtext=fontfile=path\font.ttf:text='DEF':fontcolor=black:fontsize=45:box=1:boxcolor=white@1:boxborderw=5:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=100:enable='gte(t,5)'" -codec:a copy output.mp4
```

Then you can use it like this =>

```
 addabc  video.mp4 output.mp4
```

its also possible to just use the input name and append something to it for the output file name